# Issue while installing Scipy

Tags: scipy, python-3.7

I installed `Scipy` using the command `sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy` and looks like the latest version of both are installed. But when I try to install a python package named `wfdb` using `pip install wfdb`, it get an error while `Building wheel for scipy (PEP 517)`.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
Running setup.py clean for scipy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'/tmp/pip-install- 
fhfmfpqi/scipy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install- 
fhfmfpqi/scipy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-fhfmfpqi/scipy
Complete output (9 lines):

`setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

 - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
 - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                files that aren't checked into the git repo)

 Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
 Failed to build scipy
 ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`
```

I upgraded `pip` using `pip install --upgrade pip`.

python version used: 3.7

Can I get some help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Never do `sudo pip`. Instead do `pip install --user`. Or (better) work in a virtualenv.

EDIT: typo: there is no space between `--` and `user`.

Comment: Tried `pip install -- user scipy`. I am getting this error `RROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement user (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for user`

Comment: `python -m pip install --user scipy` again gives the same error of `Failed building wheel for scipy`

Comment: What is the reason fr this advice?

Answer (score 0):

Clean out the install (I don't know which system you're using) i.e. get rid of the $PATH variables and just do a fresh install.

If you're using Anaconda:

conda install -c anaconda scipy

should do it

also the goops old

pip install scipy

gets it done as well. May I ask why you approached your installation in this way (again, I don't know which system you're on)

Comment: I am using `Raspbian` as the operating system. Earlier `python2.7` was the operating python version. I had installed `scipy, numpy and wfdb` for `python2.7`. When I upgraded the python version to 3.7 and I am getting this issue. I had installed `scipy` in `python2.7` using `sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy`, tried the same way for `python3.7`.